# Link to open Gmail/SuperHuman message

Tags: ios, gmail, deep-linking

Is there any way to create a link to open a specific message in Gmail or SuperHuman on iOS?

For Gmail I've found the scheme `googlegmail:///cv=13eafcee7cc82901/accountId=1&create-new-tab`, however I have no idea where to find such id. As the id that is now used in the web client is 64 characters long and not hexadecimal. Also, there are no mentions on how to control the account, as one typically will have the account address not the number.

There are also reports saying that this [no longer works](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/4GmP0gqEpmw), but an article written some months ago still [claims the scheme works](https://vishaldoshi.me/2018/09/10/gmail-ios-url-schemes/).

For SuperHuman I have not found anything, as it not yet not publicly available.

For the stock email app one can use `message://<insert_your_message_id@here.com>`.

Comment: I really wish someone could post about this again. Been searching for an answer to this forever.

Answer (score 0):

For **Superhuman**, the answer is **Cmd+K** and type in `Copy Page Link`.  The link will be copied to the clipboard.  Alternatively, **Ctrl+/** will do the same thing.

There is an answer over at https://webapps.stackexchange.com [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66067/55579).  The short of it to use the rfc822msgid: operator.